# Can no longer perform admin tasks on windows server 2008 (not r2)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, .net, .net-4.0

Has anyone seen an issue with deploying a .net 4.0 website to a server 2008 machine when the app pool for the site is set at 2.0? Our build server pushed the new 4.0 site to the old site where the app pool was set at 2.0 on two servers. We can no longer perform admin tasks on both servers such as opening IIS and updating the app pool. Has anyone seen this behavior and hopefully have a fix?

Note: cross posted to http://forums.iis.net/p/1171084/1954948.aspx#1954948

Comment: I've had other problems with 4.0, not this one specifically, so I'm holding off deploying it to any systems that don't absolutely need it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being with windows updates that failed to install properly. Once the server was brought up to date everything worked fine again ;)